# Render Values Based on Searching with Unique ID - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, use-effect

i use reactjs, nodejs and mysql.. which fetches datas from database.
Right now my struggle is that i need to show the row only based on search values possibly not including submit button (like google search)

here is my NodeJS fetch link, so if i enter http:\localhost\productlist\3, then it will display 3rd product only in NodeJS, but i want to implement the same functinality in reactjs as well via searchbox

```
app.get("/productslist/:idaddproducts", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.idaddproducts
  console.log(id)
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM `addproducts` where idaddproducts = ? ",id,(err, rows) => {
    if (!err) console.log(rows), res.json({ data: rows });
    //data variable is not mandatory but inorder to pass the result we need it
    else console.log(err);
    // connection.end()
  });
});
```

and Here is my react js Code

```
export default function MaterialTableDemo() {
  const initialState = {
    idaddproducts: "",
    productName: "",
    productId: "",
    productBrand: "",
    productQuantity: "",
    productPrice: "",
    productType: ""
  };
  const [poName, pnName] = React.useState(initialState);

  const handleName = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    pnName({ ...poName, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(poName);
  };

  async function handleTable(e) {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/productslist/:id");
    const data = await res.json();
    pnName(data.data);
    console.log(data.data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleTable();
  }, []);

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off" align="center">
      <div className={classes.formGroup}>
        <FormControl>
          <Input
            type="search"
            label="Product ID"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            placeholder="Enter Product ID"
            value={poName.idaddproducts}
            name="idaddproducts"
            onChange={handleName}
          />
        </FormControl>
        {poName.length &&
          poName.map(v => {
            return (
              <h4 key={v.idaddproducts}>
                {v.productName}
                {v.productId}
                {v.productBrand}
                {v.productQuantity}
                {v.productPrice}
                {v.productType}
              </h4>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Would you like to type a text in searchbox and search it in your database and show those items in your react app?

Comment: Exactly, as we type it should show possible matches in table or atleast we can add button then we type in search box and press enter to render the datas in react

Comment: Where would like to search that text? productName, productBrand? both?

Comment: Planning into search using idaddproducts which is unique value primary key.. if that works out I'll migrate same functionality to productCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works now... here is the piece of code.. thanks to those two peoples

```
export default function MaterialTableDemo() {
  const initialState = {
    idaddproducts: "",
    productName: "",
    productId: "",
    productBrand: "",
    productQuantity: "",
    productPrice: "",
    productType: ""
  };
  const [poName, pnName] = React.useState(initialState);

  const handleName = e => {
    const idAddProducts = e.target.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    pnName({ ...poName, idaddproducts: idAddProducts });
    handleTable(idAddProducts);
    console.log(poName);
  };

  async function handleTable(idAddProducts) {
    const id = poName.idaddproducts;
    const res = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:4000/productslist/" + idAddProducts
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    pnName(data.data);
    console.log(data.data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleTable();
  }, []);

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off" align="center">
      <div className={classes.formGroup}>
        <FormControl>
          <Input
            type="search"
            label="Product ID"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            placeholder="Enter Product ID"
            value={poName.idaddproducts}
            name="idaddproducts"
            onChange={handleName}
          />
          {poName.length &&
            poName.map(v => {
              return (
                <h4 key={v.idaddproducts}>
                  {v.productName}
                  {v.productId}
                  {v.productBrand}
                  {v.productQuantity}
                  {v.productPrice}
                  {v.productType}
                </h4>
              );
            })}
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[See ScreenShot](https://ibb.co/hfDW1Hkhttps://ibb.co/XY97nr2)

Answer (score 1):

```
async function handleTable(e) {
    const id = poName.idaddproducts;
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/productslist/" + id);
    const data = await res.json();
    pnName(data.data);
    console.log(data.data);
}

useEffect(() => {
    handleTable();
}, [poName.idaddproducts]);
```

Try to use like this.

Comment: What does `e` return?

Comment: when i type 10 console output is {idaddproducts: "1"}, then when i type 100 console output is {idaddproducts:"10"},  and no more data fetching

Comment: Use `onBlur` event instead of `onChange`

Comment: Nothing comes up.. not even in console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205656/discussion-between-ma-dev-15-and-logesh-p).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Check this, this will work fine]
Check this, this will work fine, if not then there will be another problem